# Spring Batch for processing CSV files

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am looking at Spring Batch (2.1.9) for processing CSV files uploaded by users. 
The flow I need to support includes two major job-templates for many file formats.

- validation of the uploaded file that includes:

  - Parsing and validating the format of all provided fields for each record (using regexp)
  - Business validation of the mapped object
  - Generating a detailed report that provides the total record count, invalid record count, and a detail of the errors (line number and all the errors found in it)

Only files that have no errors can be fully processed in a second job triggered by the user that uploaded it:

- Processing the file:

  - Parsing the file
  - storing the records to the DB (using a service call)
  - commit all the records in the uploaded file or rollback if there are errors
  - provide feedback on the processing (success or failure)

I have looked at various examples but couldn't find good examples for:

- defining regexp for the fields in an ItemReader
- collecting errors and generating file-processing report.
- commit or rollback the entire job (no commit-interval)
- using a single job definition and passing (reference?) to the CSV fields, regexp expressions, business validation service, and processing service at runtime (based on the file type)

I would appreciate any pointers to sample code that addresses these issues

Answer (score 0):

[download and run the samples yourself.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/spring-batch-samples/index.html)